# Magento2: issue with captcha in conact page

Tags: magento2, forms, captcha

In stores --> Configuration --> Configuration customer --> Captcha I have enabled captcha also for "Contact page".

After open page contact us the captcha code form is not displayed.
[image]

When I try to send msg via this form then display:
"**Incorrect captcha**"

Comment: Are you using default contact form?

Comment: yes,  you can check here: https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/contact (now is disabled captcha but after enable no display field.)